# Acceptance of SAML assetion in a multi-tenant SSO login in Pentaho with spring-SAML

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, pentaho, multi-tenant, spring-saml

I would like to configure Pentaho with a multi-tenant SSO login using the SAML Plugin [Link](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-engineering-samples/tree/master/Samples_for_Extending_Pentaho/Reference%20Implementations/Security/SAML%202.0) (that extends the Spring SAML).

Right now I have declared multiple Service Providers (SPs) and Identity Providers (IDPs) in the *blueprint.xml* (one for each tenant).

If I log with tenant2, I get a generic error page at URL https://my.application.com/pentaho/saml/SSO
and in the logs I see the exception

```
AuthNResponse;FAILURE;10.20.1.120;pentaho@tenant.1.name;tenant.2.name;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
[stacktrace]
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Local entity is not the intended audience of the assertion in at least one AudienceRestriction
```

If I check the SAML, the audience sent contains the right tenant (the second one): I think that Pentaho is analyzing any SAML epecting as if it is always from tenant1.
**How can I make Pentaho use the right tenant SP to validate the right SAML audience?**

---

*Further details from here*

---

Here is an example of the blueprint.xml setup in the SAML Plugin:

```
  <bean id="spResourceFactoryTenant1" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.sp.metadata.filesystem.tenant1}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.sp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="spResourceFactoryTenant2" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.sp.metadata.filesystem.tenant2}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.sp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="idpResourceFactoryTenant1" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.idp.metadata.filesystem.tenant1}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.idp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="idpResourceFactoryTenant2" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.idp.metadata.filesystem.tenant2}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.idp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <!-- MetadataManager configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs and SP's  -->
  <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager" depends-on="pentahoSamlBootstrap">
    <argument>
      <list>
        <!-- sp metadata with extended metadata -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="spResourceFactoryTenant1" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.incoming.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant1sp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="spResourceFactoryTenant2" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.incoming.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant2sp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>

        <!-- idp metadata -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="idpResourceFactoryTenant1" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.response.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant1idp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="idpResourceFactoryTenant2" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.response.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant2idp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>

      </list>
    </argument>
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager" />
    <property name="defaultIDP" value="${saml.idp.url}" />
  </bean>
```

With this configuration, when I go to the url
https://my.application.com/pentaho/alias/tenant2sp/sp?idp=tenant.2.name
I am redirected to the login page exposed by the IDP (WSO2) for the tenant2. After the login I am redirected to the https://my.application.com/pentaho/saml/SSO url getting a generic error: [see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2um5G.png)

> Sorry, something went wrong.
> Please try again or contact
> your system administrator.

In the logs I see

```
INFO  [SAMLDefaultLogger] AuthNResponse;FAILURE;10.20.1.120;pentaho@tenant.1.name;tenant.2.name;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:265)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
        at org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.PentahoSamlAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PentahoSamlAuthenticationProvider.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.BeanBuilder$1.invoke(BeanBuilder.java:162)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
        at org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.PentahoAuthenticationManagerDelegate.authenticate(PentahoAuthenticationManagerDelegate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:209)
        at org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.logout.PentahoSamlLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(PentahoSamlLogoutProcessingFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:168)
        at org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.logout.PentahoSamlLogoutFilter.processLogout(PentahoSamlLogoutFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:136)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.java:276)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.CsrfGateFilter.doFilter(CsrfGateFilter.java:136)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.WebappRootForwardingFilter.doFilter(WebappRootForwardingFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoPathDecodingFilter.doFilter(PentahoPathDecodingFilter.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Local entity is not the intended audience of the assertion in at least one AudienceRestriction
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAudience(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:542)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionConditions(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:494)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:339)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:250)
        ... 70 more
```

But if I check in the SAML, the expected tenant audience has been provided:

```
<saml2:AudienceRestriction>
  <saml2:Audience>pentaho</saml2:Audience>
  <saml2:Audience>pentaho@tenant.2.name</saml2:Audience>
</saml2:AudienceRestriction>
```

**How can I make Pentaho use the right tenant SP to validate the right SAML audience?**

Comment: Out of the box, Sping SAML does not have 'hosting capabilities'.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: 'Hosting capabilities' mean that you access the same application using multiple fully qualified domain names, like 'app.example.org', 'app2.example.org', 'app.test.org'.
Spring can not load different configurations for those FQDNs out of the box, you need to build this on your own.

Comment: ok, thanks!
@BernhardThalmayr do you know if the initial requested url is stored somewhere in the context? I would like to use it to make a logic.

Comment: as far as I remember, the SAML AuthnRequest is stored in the Spring SAML 'message storage', which by default is implemented via memory (http session). I implemented it differently as I could not use the default one and there was no other suitable available.